# How to input characters into spreadsheet Java

Tags: java

I'm making a visual calculator and here is my code as of now:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Visicalc {
public static int i = 0;
public static int j = 0;
public static String[][] values = new String [10][10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type 'help' if you would like to see the commands");
        String input = "";                
        while(input != "quit"){
                    input = console.nextLine();
        if (input.toLowerCase().contains("help"))
        {
            help();
        }
        else if(input.contains("print")) {
            spreadsheet(input);
        }
        else if(input.toLowerCase().contains("quit")) //Exits program is user types the word quit
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!"); //Prints Goodbye before the program exits
            return;
        }


        //else if (input != "help" || input != "print" || input != "quit") {
        //  System.out.println("Invalid command. Try again.");
        //}
        }
        }



    public static void help() {
        System.out.println("Commands:");
        System.out.println("quit This exits the spreadsheet program");
        System.out.println("help Prints out all available commands.");
        System.out.println("print This prints out the current spreadsheet in its entirety.");
        System.out.println("<cell reference> = <value> This is used to place data into a cell. Here are some examples:");
        System.out.println("Here are some examples:");
        System.out.println("A1 = 6.983");
        System.out.println("B2 = Hello there people!");
        System.out.println("C5 = 07/14/1955");
        System.out.println("<cell reference> : This is used to print the contents of a cell. This must print out exactly what was input to the cell, which is not necessarily what gets printed in the cell when the spreadsheet is printed. ");
        System.out.println("clear <cell reference> This is used to clear out a cell and make it empty.");
        System.out.println("clear This is used to clear the entire spreadsheet and make all cells empty.");
        System.out.println("sorta <cell range> This is used to sort a block of cells in ascending order. All cells in the range must be of the same type in order to be sorted. A cell range is specified as 2 cell references separated by a minus (e.g. sorta A1  B3).");
        System.out.println("sortd <cell range> Same as sorta except the cells are sorted in descending order.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("TYPE 'QUIT' IF YOU WANT TO EXIT THE PROGRAM");


    }
        public static void spreadsheet(String input) {
            values[0][0] = "              ";    values[1][0] = "              ";    values[2][0] = "              ";    values[3][0] = "              ";    values[4][0] = "              ";
            values[0][1] = "              ";    values[1][1] = "              ";    values[2][1] = "              ";    values[3][1] = "              ";    values[4][1] = "              ";
            values[0][2] = "              ";    values[1][2] = "              ";    values[2][2] = "              ";    values[3][2] = "              ";    values[4][2] = "              ";
            values[0][3] = "              ";    values[1][3] = "              ";    values[2][3] = "              ";    values[3][3] = "              ";    values[4][3] = "              ";
            values[0][4] = "              ";    values[1][4] = "              ";    values[2][4] = "              ";    values[3][4] = "              ";    values[4][4] = "              ";
            values[0][5] = "              ";    values[1][5] = "              ";    values[2][5] = "              ";    values[3][5] = "              ";    values[4][5] = "              ";
            values[0][6] = "              ";    values[1][6] = "              ";    values[2][6] = "              ";    values[3][6] = "              ";    values[4][6] = "              ";
            values[0][7] = "              ";    values[1][7] = "              ";    values[2][7] = "              ";    values[3][7] = "              ";    values[4][7] = "              ";
            values[0][8] = "              ";    values[1][8] = "              ";    values[2][8] = "              ";    values[3][8] = "              ";    values[4][8] = "              ";
            values[0][9] = "              ";    values[1][9] = "              ";    values[2][9] = "              ";    values[3][9] = "              ";    values[4][9] = "              ";

            values[5][0] = "              ";    values[6][0] = "              ";    values[7][0] = "              ";    values[8][0] = "              ";    values[9][0] = "              ";
            values[5][1] = "              ";    values[6][1] = "              ";    values[7][1] = "              ";    values[8][1] = "              ";    values[9][1] = "              ";
            values[5][2] = "              ";    values[6][2] = "              ";    values[7][2] = "              ";    values[8][2] = "              ";    values[9][2] = "              ";
            values[5][3] = "              ";    values[6][3] = "              ";    values[7][3] = "              ";    values[8][3] = "              ";    values[9][3] = "              ";
            values[5][4] = "              ";    values[6][4] = "              ";    values[7][4] = "              ";    values[8][4] = "              ";    values[9][4] = "              ";
            values[5][5] = "              ";    values[6][5] = "              ";    values[7][5] = "              ";    values[8][5] = "              ";    values[9][5] = "              ";
            values[5][6] = "              ";    values[6][6] = "              ";    values[7][6] = "              ";    values[8][6] = "              ";    values[9][6] = "              ";
            values[5][7] = "              ";    values[6][7] = "              ";    values[7][7] = "              ";    values[8][7] = "              ";    values[9][7] = "              ";
            values[5][8] = "              ";    values[6][8] = "              ";    values[7][8] = "              ";    values[8][8] = "              ";    values[9][8] = "              ";
            values[5][9] = "              ";    values[6][9] = "              ";    values[7][9] = "              ";    values[8][9] = "              ";    values[9][9] = "              ";

            if(input.contains("A1")){
                    values[0][0] = (input.substring(input.indexOf("=") + 1));
            }

          for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");   
                for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                System.out.print(values[i][j] + " | ");    
            }
            System.out.println( "" );
          }
        }
}
```

As you can see on the line:

```
    if(input.contains("A1")){
            values[0][0] = (input.substring(input.indexOf("=") + 1));
    }
```

It is supposed to change the value at top left of the spreadsheet to the value that is inputted...(for example A1 = Hello) But once that code is put in, and I print the spreadsheet again, the spreadsheet is still blank, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Spend some time learning how to debug

Comment: I've been trying for awhile, that's why I came here :(

Comment: You have a mismatch between your command and what they really do. In debugging like @OldProgrammer says you will find out really quickly.

Comment: No idea how to use the debugger as I am new to java